# How to get an ::after element adjusted in size proportionally to its containing div when the viewport-size changes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that dynamically adjusts to the available space. (It is a flex element and contains an image file.) It also has an :after element that loads a graphic via URL as a background. This graphic is a section of a tilemap. This graphic should a) dynamically adjust its position in the div (when the div changes its size) and b) scale its size proportionally. It does neither, but shifts when the viewport is resized and thus changes its position in/on the div relatively; its size, however, does not change (e.g. does not get smaller when I shrink the window). How do I get it to a) dynamically adjust its position and b) scale along reasonably (i.e. maintain its size relative to the div)? The concerning div is defined in CSS as follows:

```
.videoprev:hover::after {
    content: "";
    background: url('/images/tilemap.svg');
    background-position: -1000px -500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: scale(0.8);
}
```

Edit:
I decided to give more information to you such as html and an updated version of css.

Note that the issue with the position could be fixed by adding a "transform: translate" statement (with setting x and y to -50%). Anyway the scaling still is an issue. Remember: It should get smaller when I shrink the window, as the surrounding divs also get smaller. I'd appreciate help on this.

The width and the height have to be pixels, because they define the part of the tilemap.svg to display (note: tilemap.svg is a spritemap and thus contains many images/icons).

HTML:

```
<div class="showcase">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="video col-md-8">
            <div class="collect">
                <div class="videoplay ratio ratio-16x9">
                    <iframe src="#"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="previmg col-md-4">
            <div class="videoprev1">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="#" />
            </div>
            <div class="videoprev2">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="#" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.video {
    padding-right: 0;
}
.previmg {
    padding-left: 3vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.videoprev1,
.videoprev2 {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.videoprev1:hover::after,
.videoprev2:hover::after {
    content: '';
    background: url('/images/tilemap.svg');
    background-position: -1000px -500px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Well you're explicitly setting the width and height absolutely, so of course it won't adjust to the viewport size.

Comment: Oh, well. Is there a work-around, because it needs to be "absolute" in order to get displayed at all.

Comment: @MightyA Please include more code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Hi! Your question is hard to understand without the context - could you post the HTML and CSS for the surrounding elements please? Also do the width and height need to be in pixels, or could they be percentages, and might the background-size property be useful here?